# relative layout position programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add different views using the relative layout. The edittext and the spinner get added but the listview is not showing .Also, I am not using xmls for layout

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    Context rContext;
    private String rTitle;

    private Spinner rSpinner;
    private EditText rInput;
    private ListView rResultsList;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        rContext = context;
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int theme) {
        super(context, attrs, theme);
    }

    public void initialize(String title) {

        rTitle = title;
        rInput = new EditText(rContext);
        rInput.setId(1);
        rSpinner = new Spinner(rContext);
        rSpinner.setId(2);
        rResultsList = new ListView(rContext);
        rResultsList.setId(3);
        rInput.setText("1");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rContext, R.layout.result_item, R.id.result_item, new String[] { "this", "that" });
        rResultsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        addViews();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return rTitle;
    }

    private void addViews() {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ConvertoActivity.APP_WIDTH / 2, 100);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, rInput.getId());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ConvertoActivity.APP_WIDTH / 2, 100);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, rSpinner.getId());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rInput.getId());

        this.addView(rInput, relativeParams2);
        this.addView(rSpinner, relativeParams);
        this.addView(rResultsList, relativeParams3);


    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. 
I was adding rules to the same object of relative params.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view extends LinearLayout and you are using RelativeLayout.Layout params. Change your custom view to extend RelativeLayout.

Comment: I tried that. When I extend relative layout it shows only the listview and not the inputview and spinner

Comment: That could be because you are using three different instances of layout params. If you want to show each view components vertically, you can simply set the orientation to vertical for your lienar layout with height as WRAP_CONTENT for each item.